# Why does logical-AND take operator precedence (evaluated first) over logical-OR?

Tags: mathematical-logic

Does logical-AND have precedence over logical-OR because of a reason or was it an arbitrary choice made sometime in the distant past?

(Perhaps it could have been the other way around: OR-terms evaluated first, then AND'ed together?)

I've Googled and can't seem to find an answer; most mathematical and computer language references state the precedence rankings of various operations but not the origins.

NOTE: I don't believe this question has anything to do with notation, but rather the order that operations are performed.

Comment: *I don't believe this question has anything to do with notation, but rather the order that operations are performed.* I don't think this is right. It's purely a notational thing. It's a rule about how to interpret the order of operations given the notation.

Comment: This WP article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective#Order_of_precedence says that the precedence you refer to isn't standardized.

Answer (score 7):

"And" is often seen as the multiplication in Boole's algebra, sometime written $\times$ and "Or" is seen as the addition (and sometime written $+$, though $+$ is more often used for xor than for or), which is why they commonly inherit the precedance of their namesakes.

Note that both are distributive over the other, and it's the neutral element (0 for or, 1 for and) that gives the correspondance.

So the next question that has to be addressed is why multiplication usually has precedence over addition (note that some programming languages, notably, do not follow this convention).

It [seems](https://web.archive.org/web/20180111045655/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52582.html) to have arisen from a global consensus, mainly over concerns of simplicity of writing polynomials, but wasn't formalised until the 20th century. This is because mathematicians don't care so much about precedence, but wider teaching of mathematics in textbooks, as well as the rise of IT-science, have made it compulsory to formalise these rules.

Comment: +1 it goes back to Boole.  Of course Boole did not use a star $*$ for and, he used the normal notations for multiplication.  Say $xy+z$ meaning "($x$ and $y$) or $z$".

Comment: The next question is where the multiplication/addition convention in algebra came from, there is a well sourced answer on Math Forum http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52582.html. It "appears to have arisen naturally and without much disagreement as algebraic notation was being developed in the 1600s... This is probably because the distributive property implies a natural hierarchy in which multiplication is more powerful than addition, and makes it desirable to be able to write polynomials with as few parentheses as possible."

Comment: @Conifold do you mind if I edit my answer to adress this as well? It seems relevant and interesting, but may be a bit off topic

Comment: Sure, go ahead. I don't think it would be off topic, since Boole simply borrowed a convention from algebra addressing it is a natural part of the explanation.

Comment: The analogy with multiplication is reinforced by the fact that a Boolean algebra is essentially the same thing as a ring in which every element is idempotent. See [Boolean ring - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring).